# Can't find image path in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to display images from an array in Vue.js. The problem is that when I try to implement images inside component it says can't find that image from that path. the component is located inside the components folder and the images are located inside the assets folder. I tried even create images folder and move those images from assets into images folder but it still shows the same error.

```
 <div v-for="number in [currentNumber]" :key='number'>
        <img :src="require(currentImage)" />
      </div>
...
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data() {
    return {
      images: ['../assets/img1.jpg','../assets/img2.jpg'],
      currentNumber: 0,
    }
  },
```

I tried even moving out the images from assets into separate image folder:

```
 images: ['../images/img1.jpg','../images/img2.jpg'],
```

The problem was the same. I checked other similiar questions in Stack Overflow but none of them worked. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have to require the `image` instead:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      image: require('~/path_to_image')
    }
  },
```

Comment: So how will look like the above array of the images in my question if I create a separate static folder?

Comment: For this line: images: ['../images/img1.jpg','../images/img2.jpg'],

Comment: Sorry for **static** folder, I thought you were using Nuxt.js (but the code above is Ok becuase Nuxt.js = Vue.js + SSR)

Comment: Your code looks good for one image while I am using an array of images as you see. So how will look like your solution for this array?
images: ['../images/img1.jpg','../images/img2.jpg'],
Where exactly to add require in this case?

Comment: Is there another solution? because in this case, it becomes quite complicated for iterating.

Comment: Declare each image individually in that object returned by `data()` (as I did for `image` above, and just add a comma at the end of that line to declare a new image )